# Mapping data in Laravel to a JSON object

Tags: php, json, backbone.js, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to convert data retrieved from my Laravel model to a JSON object as outlined in the [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap).

My problem is that when I encode the data all I get are the public properties and none of the (protected) attributes - the ones I actually want. This is how I go about it:

***Controller***

```
$movie = Movie::with('awards.award', 'customAwards.awardCustom', 'cast.person', 'imdb.rottenTomatoes')->find($id);

return View::make('movie')->with(array(
    'movie'     => $movie
));
```

***View***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    DS.Resources.Movie = {{json_encode($movie)}};
</script>
```

***DS.Resources.Movie output***

```
{
    "timestamps":false,
    "incrementing":true,
    "exists":true
}
```

If I `var_dump` `$movie` I can see the protected attributes like title, year, a cast collection, awards collection etc. How do I access these properties and map them to my JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eloquent, you should use `->toJson()` as it correctly only gets the model's attributes, rather than general class properties. Similarly, it'll get your relationships if you used a `->with()` I think.

If you don't want certain attributes to come out in the JSON (like password fields) you can specify an array in your class called `hidden`, see [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json).

Answer (score 1):

You should unprotect them in your model.
Also you should realize you can use `->toJson()` on your model instead of json_encode'ing it.